# Run a .sql file in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rake

I am trying to start working on a Ruby codebase and working on adding a new Rake task.
I am trying to run a .sql file on my connected mySQL database.

```
namespace :db do
  task :seed do
    connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
    puts connection
    sql = File.read('./docker/seed/warehouse-b2b/addresses.sql')
    statements = sql.split(/;$/)
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      statements.each do |statement|
        connection.execute(statement)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here's how I invoke the task `rake db:seed --trace`.
Here's the error stack trace that I get

```
Mysql2::Error: Query was empty: 
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.1.10.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:288:in `query'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.1.10.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:288:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.1.10.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:245:in `block in log'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.1.10.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.1.10.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:240:in `log'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-3.1.10.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:288:in `execute'
tasks/common_db_seed.rake:15:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
tasks/common_db_seed.rake:14:in `each'
tasks/common_db_seed.rake:14:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

New to Ruby, can't figure out the problem. Any help appreciated!

Comment: The actual error message is missing. Please post the command in te CLI and the whol error output.

Comment: There are some organisational restrictions because of which I cannot post that :( however, the error that I get is in the first trace error statement of the stack trace that I have posted. What is it that you're looking for exactly?

Answer (score -2):

By convention, the db seeding must be done on seeds.rb file